# NodeJS Child Process truncate output string with ellipsis

Tags: node.js, powershell, child-process

I'm currently developing an application using Electron.
One of the actions this application does is "verify the version" of a TeamSpeak 3 Client-addon.
To do this, I run a command that checks the SHA256 hash of the addon file, and compare it against another string.

```
powershell.exe Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\TS3Client\plugins\tokovoip_win32.dll
```

I run the same command for `tokovoip_win64.dll`. This works, for most people. However, for one of the users of my application, it breaks.

After running a regular expression over the command

```js
const win32ActualHash = /SHA256\s+?(\S+?)\s/gm.exec(await child.execSync(
    'powershell.exe Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\\TS3Client\\plugins\\tokovoip_win32.dll'))[1];
const win64ActualHash = /SHA256\s+?(\S+?)\s/gm.exec(await child.execSync(
    'powershell.exe Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\\TS3Client\\plugins\\tokovoip_win64.dll'))[1];
```

the expected output is

```js
win32ActualHash = 'DDCF282FDC439DE4E560F74231B22850EB7016573730A0CD94B08AAEECDEC167';
win64ActualHash = 'AA38ED69966741C4D68E964F05CB16351EC5700E337D953B07DB81D7FB3891C7';
```

However, the output this user gets, is

```js
win32ActualHash = 'DDCF282FDC439DE4E560F74231B22850EB7016573730A0CD94B08AAEECDE...';
win64ActualHash = 'AA38ED69966741C4D68E964F05CB16351EC5700E337D953B07DB81D7FB38...';
```

I have a very limited setup to test solutions, as I'm not able to recreate this scenario, and I don't want to spam this user with possible fixes.

What is causing these strings to be truncated, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this by piping it into `Format-List` within the powershell command:

```
powershell.exe "Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\TS3Client\plugins\tokovoip_win32.dll  | Format-List"
```

And then changing the RegExp to extract the hash

```js
const win32ActualHash = /Hash\s*?:\s*(\S*)\s*/gm.exec(await child.execSync(
            'powershell.exe "Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\\TS3Client\\plugins\\tokovoip_win32.dll | Format-List"'))[1];
        const win64ActualHash = /Hash\s*?:\s*(\S*)\s*/gm.exec(await child.execSync(
            'powershell.exe "Get-FileHash $env:APPDATA\\TS3Client\\plugins\\tokovoip_win64.dll | Format-List"'))[1];
```

The `Format-List` never seems to truncate strings and thus delivers a consistent output